# Where in this loop re-writes b to 29?

Tags: r

I have the following loop:

```
    n_range <- 4:29
bResultsStra <- vector("double", 27)
for (b in n_range) { 
  bRowsStra<-Stratified[sample(nrow(Stratified), b), ]
  base <- read.table("base.csv", header=T, sep="," )
  base$area<-5036821
  base$quadrea <- base$area * 16
  bootStra <- boot(data=bRowsStra$count, average, R=1000)
  base$data<- bootStra$t
  base$popsize<-(base$data*base$quadrea)
  basesortStra <- base[order(base$popsize),]
  bValue <- basesortStra$popsize[975] - basesortStra$popsize[25]
  bResultsStra[[b - 1]] <- bValue
  }
```

which I changed from

```
n_range <- 2:29
bResultsStra <- vector("double", 29)
```

Basically, I no longer want to take values from n=2,3.
However, when I run and attempt to put it in a data frame it returns:

```
Error in data.frame(n = n_range, bResultsStra) : 
arguments imply differing number of rows: 26, 28
```

For some reason I do not know, b gets written to

```
29L
```

rather than 27 which it should from the `n_range`. Why is it doing this?
Thank You

Comment: Your `n_range` has the value `4:29`. Why are you confused that `b` takes on the value 29 when looping over it?

Comment: Ah I see, sorry I meant, why is the loop producing 28 variables (and hence unable to input it into a dataframe of 4-29), when the n_range is 4:29. It seems b is going to 2 rather than stopping at 4?

Answer (score 0):

The offending line is

```
bResultsStra[[b - 1]] <- bValue
```

**That’s the problem with [magic constants](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Magic_number_%28programming%29)**: once you change one of them, the relationship with the other constants in the code gets lost.

To fix this *and* make your code more robust at the same time, change your code as follows:

```
from <- 4L
to <- 29L

n_range <- seq(from, to)
bResultsStra <- vector("double", length(n_range))

for (b in n_range) { 
    # […]
    bResultsStra[[b - from + 1L]] <- bValue
}
```

That said, this code could be improved further by choosing better variable names (even just consistent naming conventions go a long way!) and by replacing the entire loop with a call to `lapply`.